# How can I find anagram words in an array using a dictionary

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C#. I need some help. Here's the code I made:

```
static void anagrame_dict(String [] s)
{
    ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
    foreach (string cuv in s)
    {
        Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        foreach (char lit in cuv)
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(lit))
            {
                dict[lit] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                dict[lit] = 1;
            }
        }
        x.Add(dict);
    }
    ..............
```

I made an arraylist of dictionaries but now I don't know how to access the keys and values in every dictionary from the arraylist to compare them and see which words are anagrams.

This is a sample

```
input String[]b={ "casa", "djf", "ajkd", "saca", "asca", "lama", "ajs", "mala", "kasa", "saka", "idm", "kaj", "hfk" };
```

By anagrams I mean words with same characters but different order like "casa" and "saca".

Comment: What do you need Dictionaries for if you want to find anagrams? How do you define an "anagram" exactly? And finally: I would not suggest to use [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-6.0#remarks), you can (and should) use a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) instead.

Comment: Please provide a sample input for string s, and what your expected output should be, are you planning on having the dictionary filled with anagrams or something?

Comment: I think you're looking for palindromic words...words that spell the same thing back and forward. Anagram words (that make single 'other' words) require lookups

Comment: If you sort each word letters (like "casa" =>"aacs") you will see two anagram words have the same sorted output. Then for each word, check if myDict.Contains("aacs") and if not, add it like myDict["aacs"]="casa".

Comment: @Madalina, be kind and upvote your accepted answer. There is some effort into that response...

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli A user needs at least 15 reputation points to upvote, so Madalina can't upvote yet.

Comment: Oh! I forgot about that rule. Forget what I said then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two strings, they are anagrams of each other if you SORT their characters and the resulting sorted sequences are the same.

Here's a lambda that receives a string and returns its characters in sorted order:

```
Func<String, String> sorted = w => new String(w.ToCharArray().OrderBy(c => c).ToArray());
```

Example usage:

```
String word = "alphabet";
Console.WriteLine(word + " ==> " + sorted(word));
```

Output:

```
alphabet ==> aabehlpt
```

Now we can iterate over each word in your input array and get the sorted "signature" of it. As we iterate, we'll ask the array to find all other words in the array that are not the current word, but do have a matching "signature".

We can use a `Dictionary<String, List<String>>` to associate each source word with a list of any anagrams found.

Here's the whole thing put together:

```
String[] words ={ "casa", "djf", "ajkd", "saca", "asca", "lama", "ajs", "mala", "kasa", "saka", "idm", "kaj", "hfk" };

Func<String, String> sorted = w => new String(w.ToCharArray().OrderBy(c => c).ToArray());

Dictionary<String, List<String>> anagrams = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (String word in words)
{
    var matches = words.Where(w => w != word && sorted(w) == sorted(word)).ToList();
    anagrams.Add(word, matches);
}

foreach (var result in anagrams)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Key + " ==> " + String.Join(", ", result.Value));
}
```

Output:

```
casa ==> saca, asca
djf ==>
ajkd ==>
saca ==> casa, asca
asca ==> casa, saca
lama ==> mala
ajs ==>
mala ==> lama
kasa ==> saka
saka ==> kasa
idm ==>
kaj ==>
hfk ==>
```